# GO Continuous Delivery - How Go Runs shell scripts ?

Tags: bash, shell, go-cd

Sorry for the stupid question in advance , but I'm having a problem finding my issue in the official documentation .

So I have a pipeline which pulls from Git and I have a job which extracts the name of the release which was updated in Git , the problem is that I'm setting the release name  as an environment variable, but when I run another job this is not picked up by the 2nd job (shell script ) . Does anybody has the same issue as me and knows a workaround . I'm curious how GO runs the shell script . If I run the shell script manually logged in as GO user it works .

Thanks and sorry again . 
Istvan C.

Comment: Show the command pipeline you are running, point us to which part is setting the env. variable and to which part that should use that env variable. Now - keep in mind that a process can only set an env variable that becomes visible in a child process.

Comment: I'm having in one stage a shell script which sets the env with an echo to the bash_profile of go . And in the second pipeline a printenv .